# Error when trying to run WAMP in windows7?

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wamp

I have download wamp2.5 from [wamp download link](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).
I have installed it in my local machine but when i am trying to run it its giving me error.

[image: error image when running wamp]

When i google it it says try to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64) its install successfully but it still running wamp giving me same error when i am trying to install Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)  even in 64bit machine becuase php use some of the 32bit libraries.
   when i download Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) from [c++ 2010 redistributable x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=14632&cffa64c5-a636-96fc-e97a-0e907fcc4c04=True) 
   but when i run x86 i am getting this error.
[image: x86 error].

when i am trying to install C++ 2008 redistributable copy again getting error.
   [image: C++ 2008 installation error]

How can i get rid of this error?

Comment: Funny enough, it's because you don't have [Visual C++ 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29). Also, you may need both the 64 bit and 32 bit versions of 2010.

Comment: let me install visual c++ 2008

Comment: @Ohgodwhy  can u please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to find it inside /windows/system32? Otherwise download it and put there. the message is clear, is missing a dll.

Comment: can u please tell me in detail what should i need to check in /windows/system32   when i am trying to install C++ 2008 i am getting error which is the last snapshot of my question

Comment: Yes I can, go to the system32 folder and check this dll "MSVCR110.DLL" if you do not have it, try to download because you should have it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem too.But then I figured it out.By Simply search for "Services" that is if you're running windows 7/8.Scroll and look for "SQL Server reporting Services" and try to stop it.
Then go back to Wamp icon left click and Restart All Services.Hope it works.